# Excessive stat calls on /etc/localtime in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone

I just straced my Rails-App and it produces a lot of

```
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2309, ...}) = 0
```

Calls (really a lot!).
In other contexts I've read that this is because the Timezone is not set.
Is there a way to "fix" this?

Best,

Tobias

Comment: I think you'd better report this to the Rails forums instead of SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a ruby issue but rather a C / Linux issue:
Setting "TZ" ENV-Var will lead to no more stat calls on etc/localtime.
It wont have significant performance impacts though:

```
# irb
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.measure { 10_000_000.times { Time.now } }
 =>  17.880000   0.540000  18.420000 ( 21.535307)

# same with TZ=CET irb
 =>  18.040000   0.550000  18.590000 ( 20.892542)
```

Comment: Maybe it can have significant perf impact in some contexts?  I'm administering rather than developing it, but I just did an strace of a newly-deployed Rails app and got *ONLY* thousands of lines of statting localtime - and the threads were chewing up CPU like crazy.  "echo 'export TZ='America/Chicago'' >> /etc/sysconfig/httpd" and a restart of httpd/Rack (Passenger) processes and it's running waaaaaaaaay better, even after several minutes and some load has resumed.  I'll see how it holds.  Thanks for the TZ env pointer!

Answer (score 1):

As @fabio said, you should report this to the Rails forums or mailinglist, because its probably a bug.

However, to set the time zone, in your `config/environment.rb`:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
end
```

you can get available time zones with `rake time:zones:us`, `rake time:zones:local`, or `rake time:zones:all` (depending on where you are in the world.)